# Resource for honours linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, learning

I joined an honours linear algebra course late in the year and I've been finding it very difficult to understand the material in our class and homework. We don't have a textbook, and the questions often involve a lot of proof and strong understanding of concepts that aren't explicitly talked about in class. Is there any online resource that goes through linear algebra in depth?

I know I could ask my professor, but as a student who's usually somewhat good at math I just feel really awkward and would like to at least learn what I can on my own before I go and ask her.

Comment: Just to be honest with you. Go and ask your teacher :). There is nothing awkward about asking for advice ;-). If you still refuse to do that ... There are great lectures on linear algebra on youtube.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, you're right... I guess I just currently have so many questions that I feel like it'll take a few hours to get through them all, and she's very nice but also a very busy person